# How do I write Verilog testcases in Perl?

Tags: perl, verilog, system-verilog

I have simple [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) code and a test bench for which I have to pass the test cases using Perl. I have to write a Perl script of test cases which will receive random input. When I execute the Perl script, it will ask for input and whatever I input it will show "the test case has passed".

I tried using [Verilog-Perl](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-perl) but it has many `.pm` files and it is somewhat difficult to utilize them. Can anyone give me hints for this?

Comment: How much of this infrastructure already exists vs. you are building now? Can you describe what your design is doing at a high-level or explain some more about how you would like the TB to work? Do you need to glue perl directly to the simulator, or use it to generate stimulus files as toolic suggests?

Comment: Actually I need to glue perl directly so that I can pass any testcase.And I want to write this cases in perl script.e.g.If I have 8:1 mux.v and mux_tb.v file,now using run.csh(script) file I can simulate .v file and pass the cases.Now the same thing would be using run.pl and inputs of testcases would be in perl file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Verilog-Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Verilog-Perl) is most often used for parsing Verilog files, not for creating testcases.

You could use Perl to generate input stimulus files filled with random numerical data.  A simple way to read the files into your testbench is to use the `$readmemh` Verilog system task during simulation.  One benefit is that this avoids recompiling your Verilog code each time you run a new test.

Once the simulation has completed, you could also use Perl to parse the simulation log file to determine and report pass/fail status of the test.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) which is a very popular testing framework in Perl.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP:  `Test::More` is used to create tests to check Perl code. It is not typically used to create tests to check Verilog code (via simulations).